# Autowired constructor ignored for a webservice

Tags: java, spring, annotations, autowired

When deploying the default constructor is used, when running the default constructor is used.
When using the autowired setter this one is used at running the webservice , it is not executed at deploy.

I understand from other topics that there are problems when there are more autowired constructors, but here is only one and the default which has no annotation.
Is there a solution to have the autowired constructor used instead of the default one? The field which this one is setting is required.

Thank you!

```
@Autowired(required = true)
public MyWebserviceImpl(final Field field)
{
    System.out.println("I am in autowired constructor");
    this.field = field;
}


/*
 * @Autowired
 * public void setField(final Field field)
 * {
 * System.out.println("I am in autowired Setter");
 * this.field = field;
 * }
 */


@Autowired(required = false)
public MyWebserviceImpl()
{
    System.out.println("I am in default constructor");
}
```

Comment: How about removing default constructor?

Comment: it returns an error when running the webservice - it feels like the webservice needs it.

Comment: You shouldn't need the default constructor, if it is needed it isn't Spring that is controlling the construction of the webservice in the first place and the `@Autowired` doesn't work then.

Comment: well I removed the default constructor and at deployment this error was generated: Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0048: Konnte Standard-Konstruktor für class <package>.MyWebserviceImpl nicht finden\"}}"   which in English means it could not find default constructor for the class.

Comment: The class is annotated with HandlerChain  and WebService  - I really do not have experience with webservices, but if I am not wrong, these are Spring annotations.

Comment: What class extends MyWebservice or which interface it implements? Is this class annotated with `@Component` `@Service`? Or is this class created in `@Configuration` class?

Comment: It extends a class (cannot write the name here as it is from the business) which has no annotation and which has a method processInjection annotated with PostConstruct , the doc says it is needed as autowiring with SpringBeanAutowiringSupport  cannot work with spring cloud config, It also implements PortType interface annotated with webservice and XmlSeeAlso which is generated from an .xsd.